# Can you call a C# DLL from a C DLL?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, dll, cross-platform

I've built a DLL in C#. Now I want to use the [R Environment](http://www.r-project.org/) to call functions in that DLL. The R environment supports calling unmanaged C/C++ DLL's but not into .NET DLL's. So my question is, can I call functions in a C# DLL from a C/C++ DLL? If so, do you have a link to info about how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling C# from C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428267/calling-c-sharp-from-c)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most straight forward way of doing this is to expose one of the C# classes in your C# DLL as a COM object, and then create an instance of it from your C/C++ DLL. If that isn't an acceptable option, you'd need to create a mixed-mode C++ DLL (which contains both managed and unmanaged code). Your C/C++ DLL can call exported functions in your mixed-mode DLL, which can in turn forward the calls on to your C# class.

Comment: That mixed mode C++ DLL sounds like it would do the trick - I've just had a look at the templates available to create a mixed mode DLL project using VS2008 but don't see one. How would you go about starting off a mixed mode DLL?

Comment: If you create a new C++ Class Library, that creates a C++ .NET DLL project. As long as the "Common Language Runtime support" setting is set to "Common Language Runtime support (/clr)", you are free to use both managed and unmanaged code in the project.

Answer (score 3):

This article might help you out:

[CLR Hosting APIs (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163567.aspx)

**Updated:** There's a tool called [mergebin](http://sqlite-dotnet2.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sqlite-dotnet2/SQLite.NET/tools/mergebin/) that ships with the [.NET SQLite wrapper](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) you can use to create a mixed mode native/managed DLL. Grab the source code from:

[SQLite for ADO.NET 2.0 (SourceForge)](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=132486&package_id=145568)

You'll find the exe in the `bin\tools` folder.

Kev

Answer (score 1):

It is actually pretty easy.  Just use NuGet to add the "UnmanagedExports" package to your .Net project.  See https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports for details.

You can then export directly, without having to do a COM layer.  Here is the sample C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;

class Test
{
    [DllExport("add", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static int TestExport(int left, int right)
    {
        return left + right;
    }
}
```

R should be able to load TextExport just like a regular C dll.