# calling C++ functions containing callbacks in C#

Tags: c#, c++, api, callback, dllimport

hey all im trying to get my head around calling this c++ function in c#:

```
BOOL __stdcall CodecStart(int hRadio,void __stdcall (*CallbackFunc)(void *),void *CallbackTarget);
```

this is from a WinRadio api found here http://www.winradio.com/home/g305_sdk.htm.

i did find that other people asked about calling this specific function on the net and they had:

```
    public delegate void CallbackFunc( IntPtr p);

    [DllImport("WRG305API.dll")]
    public static extern bool CodecStart(int hRadio, CallbackFunc func, IntPtr CallbackTarget);
```

but i cant figure out how to implement this further.

any thoughts or guidance as to how to call this?

many thanks

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728325/can-you-call-a-c-sharp-dll-from-a-c-dll/730371#730371

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple implementation that will put it all together.

```
class WinRadioWrapper
{
    public delegate void CallbackFunc( IntPtr pData );

    [DllImport( "WRG305API.dll" )]
    public static extern bool CodecStart( int hRadio, CallbackFunc func, IntPtr CallbackTarget );

    public bool CodecStartTest(int hRadio)
    {
        bool bStarted = CodecStart( hRadio, MyCallbackFunc, IntPtr.Zero );
        return bStarted;
    }

    // Note: this method will be called from a different thread!
    static void MyCallbackFunc( IntPtr pData )
    {
        // Sophisticated work goes here...
    }
}
```

- Note that because `MyCallbackFunc` will be executed on a different thread, I chose to make is `static`. This way you won't be tempted to access `WinRadioWrapper` data members.
- For simplicity I passed an `IntPtr.Zero` parameter to the callback, but this can point to any data that you'd like to use in the callback.
  ***[Please ignore this paragraph]** Look into `Marshal.StructureToPtr` if you'd like to pass data to the callback, but make sure to also **pin** the data that you're passing in order to make sure it's not garbage-collected (see `GCHandle` for more details).*

**EDIT:**

With the interesting words by [svick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41071/svick) (thanks!), I realize I was mixing a copied object with a pinned one.

So, to sort things out:

- `Marshal.StructureToPtr` should be used if you want to copy an existing data structure and then pass it to the callback function.
- If, on the other hand, you'd like to use and existing data structure (e.g. for modifying its content), the you should use `GCHandle` in order to *pin* it in memory and prevent it from being garbage-collected.
  This, however, will add some maintenance overhead for the `GCHandle`.

Comment: You don't need to pin data that you pass to `StructureToPtr()`, because it creates a copy of the object.

Comment: What happens if you want to pass the `this` class instance as `IntPtr`?

Comment: You mean without copying? You can't do that, I think.

Comment: Important stuff.. I'll update my answer. Thanks for the eye-opening session.

Comment: I have a similar problem except my callback always returns 1.....
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59504565/c-sharp-dllimport-calling-un-managed-c-function-callback)

Answer (score 0):

A [callback function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa190117%28v=office.10%29.aspx) is a code that is called by a dll (you're importing in this case) that performs some functions. You also need to learn how to work with [delegates in c#](http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/explaining-delegates-in-c.aspx). You can implement the code like this:

```
public void MyCallback(IntPtr p)
{
    //do something
}
```

and then your dll call will be like this:

```
[DllImport("WRG305API.dll")]
    public static extern bool CodecStart(int hRadio, func, IntPtr CallbackTarget);
```

If you need more guidance, post the C++ version of the code you want to convert and we can help you with the C# version.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to create a c# function that matches the signature of the delegate you declared. Create a delegate, hold on to a reference to this delegate so it doesn't get garbage collected, and call the dll import with the delegate as the callback.

so you would having something like this:

```
public void MyCallback(IntPtr P)
{
    //do something
}

// somewhere else in your code
var cb = new CallbackFunc(MyCallback);
CodecStart(..., cb, ...);
```