# C# DllImport calling un-managed C++ function callback

Tags: c#, c++, function, pointers, dllimport

Hi I have a C# WinForm app, I am able to call functions from the `libnetclient.dll` via DllImport like below:

```
[DllImport("libnetclient.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int NETCLIENT_Initialize(int bPriorRGB16 = 0);
```

I am then able to use the functions as normal such as below:

```
int ini = NETCLIENT_Initialize();
memoBox.AppendText("NETCLIENT_Initialize = " + ini.ToString()+Environment.NewLine);//append to box
```

This callback occurs once the login function has completed.

My problem is with a callback function.

Inside the C++ `netclient.h` header file the pointer looks like this below:

```
NETCLIENT_API int API_CALL NETCLIENT_RegLoginMsg(void* pUsr, void (CALLBACK * FUNLoginMsgCB)(int nMsg, void * pUsr));
```

I tried to call this in C# like such:

```
public delegate void FUNLoginMsgCB(int nMsg, IntPtr pUsr);
....
....
[DllImport("libnetclient.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int NETCLIENT_RegLoginMsg(IntPtr pUsr, FUNLoginMsgCB _callback);

private void loginbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var _callback = new FUNLoginMsgCB(DoLoginMsgCB);
  NETCLIENT_RegLoginMsg(this.Handle, _callback);//call the callback function
}

private static void DoLoginMsgCB(int nMsg, IntPtr pUsr)
 {
   switch (nMsg)//switch shows result after login function called
    {
      case 0:
          MessageBox.Show("LOGIN_SUC");
          break;
      case 1:
          MessageBox.Show("LOGIN_FAILED");
          break;
      case 2:
          MessageBox.Show("LOGIN_DISCNT");
          break;
      case 3:
          MessageBox.Show("LOGIN_NAME_ERR");
          break;
      default:
          MessageBox.Show("DEFAULT");               
          break;
   }
}
```

However no matter what I do the result is always 1. I have double checked my login details and all are correct. If anyone has any advice or examples it'll be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to decorate the C# declaration of callback using `[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]` attribute?

Comment: yes I have called it like so `[DllImport("libnetclient.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]`

Comment: Sorry, I'm talking about `FUNLoginMsgCB` delegate declaration

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it seems to behave the same, no change.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I think I am calling the `IntPtr pUsr` incorrectly maybe I don't understand. In C# `IntPtr pUsr` is the equivalent to `void* pUsr` but in my case it was suppost to be `this` meaning the form...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I figured it out. I was using `IntPtr pUsr` incorrectly since it could be pointing to anything in my case it was pointing to `this` meaning the windows form.

Also all `DLLs` had to be called by `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall` some were left on `CharSet = CharSet.Auto` .....

This now works.

```
public delegate void FUNLoginMsgCB(int nMsg, Form1 form1);
....
....
[DllImport("libnetclient.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int NETCLIENT_RegLoginMsg(Form1 form1, FUNLoginMsgCB _callback);

private void loginbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var _callback = new FUNLoginMsgCB(DoLoginMsgCB);
  NETCLIENT_RegLoginMsg(this, _callback);//call the callback function
}

private static void DoLoginMsgCB(int nMsg, Form1 form1)
 {
   switch (nMsg)//switch shows result after login function called
    {
      case 0:
          MessageBox.Show("LOGIN_SUC");
          break;
      case 1:
          MessageBox.Show("LOGIN_FAILED");
          break;
      case 2:
          MessageBox.Show("LOGIN_DISCNT");
          break;
      case 3:
          MessageBox.Show("LOGIN_NAME_ERR");
          break;
      default:
          MessageBox.Show("DEFAULT");               
          break;
   }
}
```